# unite returning error 'no applicable method for 'unite_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
p = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
q = c("fr", "", "fr", "fe", "fre")
b = c(1, "", 1, "", 1)
a = c("r", "f", "b", "m", "p")

df=data.frame(p, q, b, a)
```

I want to unite q, b, and a, and put the result in a new column, so I use unite:

```
new_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Merged = unite(q,b,a), sep = "_")
```

I get this error:

> Error in UseMethod("unite_") :
>    no applicable method for 'unite_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Also, independent of the question above, how can I specify a **range** of columns in the code so that I don't have to enter all of them manually (I want to unite dozens of columns). Can I write `q:a` for columns q to a? I've tried this syntax with the paste function, but it didn't work.

Comment: Note I've tried to add as.character as well. The error is the same.

Comment: This is how you can specify range of columns you want to unite: `df %>% unite(Merged, q:a, sep = "_")`

Comment: @sm925 many thanks, it worked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We use `unite` outside  the `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
     unite(Merged, q, b, a, sep= "_")
```

The usage for `unite` is

> `unite(data, col, ..., sep = "_", remove = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)`

where

> `col` - The name of the new column, as a string or symbol.

---

Or another option is `transmute` with `str_c`

```
library(stringr)

df %>%
    transmute(p, Merged = str_c(q, b, a, sep="_"))
```

Comment: Style question: Why is `unite` outside the `mutate`? The way the OP used it seems more natural.

Comment: @its.me.adam there are certain functions that does things outside mutate i.e. `add_count` or `count` or `separate` or `extract` or `unite` which requires an input data.frame/tibble/data.table object instead of a vector whereas `mutate/summarise` are common transformation/summmarisation functions on which we may use `min/max/sum/...`etc.  The `unite` is a special form or `paste`.  Although, we can replicate some behavior with `paste` or `str_c` within `mutate`.  But, `unite` is handy when there are `NA` elements in a row where can use `na.rm = TRUE` to remove those NAs before concatenating

Comment: Thanks I understand that. What I want to ask is why `unite` was conceptualized in this way. Anyway, I was not aware of `str_c` so I tried it. It also removes NAs before concatenating. So for the OP would not `Merged = str_c(q,b,a)` be best inside mutate?

Comment: @its.me.adam it would be inside `mutate` or can be done outside as well using `with(df, str_c(q, b, a))`. It is from `stringr`.  I don't know why they create a function with a specific set of properties.  Maybe, they find `unite` more appropriate in understanding than the already existing functions.  I don't know the correct reason

Comment: Ah gotchya - thanks akrun! I admit I don't see the point of `unite` if I can use `str_c` together with `mutate`.

Comment: @its.me.adam you are right and `unite` may not be that efficient considered to str_c or paste (if you do a benchmark).  These are convenient functions that can be used in a way so that people don't have to write documentation for each step as it is self evident